# Check if input field value is included in array - Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, input

I'm trying to fire a function if an input field's value is equal to that of a number in an array.

I have my code below, but it doesn't seem to work!!

```
var num1 = $("#people-number").val();
var Numberarray = [1,3,5,7,9];

if ($.inArray(num1,Numberarray) > -1) {
     $("#valid-people").hide();
     $("#non-valid-people").fadeIn();   
}
```

Any tips would be appreciated.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the array has int values and the the value you are testing is a string

```
$.inArray(parseInt(num1),Numberarray)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PVPRh/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast `num1` to number.

```
if ($.inArray(+num1,Numberarray) > -1)
```

or

```
if ($.inArray(parseInt(num1, 10),Numberarray) > -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Test it with:

```
var num1 = $("#people-number").val(); var Numberarray = [1,3,5,7,9];

if ($.inArray(parseInt(num1),Numberarray) > -1) {
    $("#valid-people").hide();
    $("#non-valid-people").fadeIn();   
}
```

And return any result. Here it works: http://jsfiddle.net/fjorgemota/q6WJA/